# ion - current image as placeholder

Tags: android, android-ion

I use com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion for download image to ImageView:

```
void ChangeImage()
{
  Ion.with(imageView).error(R.drawable.request_error).load(nextHttpUrl);
}
```

When begins loading next image, the current image disappears and while the next request is loading, ImageView does not contain any images (or, if I add .placeholder() - contains a picture from resources).

How I leave as placheholder current image? Or any other way that the current image on ImageView is changed only after the complete download the next?

Answer (score 1):

Try `.crossfade()`, that will crossfade from the existing image.

Comment: Thanks! I found only a little help on github.com/koush/ion, there is somewhere a detailed guide to ion? Or ion-sample source only?